# Is there a reason for this difference between Python threads and processes?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.9

When a list object is passed to a python (3.9) Process and Thread, the additions to the list object done in the *thread* are seen in the parent but not the additions done in the *process*. E. g.,

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread


def job(x, out):
    out.append(f'f({x})')


out = []
pr = Process(target=job, args=('process', out))
th = Thread(target=job, args=('thread', out))
pr.start(), th.start()
pr.join(), th.join()
print(out)
```

This prints `['f(thread)']`. I expected it to be (disregard the order) `['f(thread)', 'f(process)']`.

Could someone explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing Python-specific about it; that's just how processes work.

Specifically, all threads running within a given process share the process's *memory-space* -- so e.g. if thread A changes the state of a variable, thread B will "see" that change.

Processes, OTOH, each get their own private memory space that is inaccessible to all other processes.  That's done deliberately as a way to prevent process A from accidentally (or deliberately) reading or corrupting the memory of process B.

When you spawn a child process, the new child process gets its own memory-space that initially contains a copy of all the data in the parent's memory space, but it is a separate space, so changes made by the child will not be visible to the parent (and vice-versa).

Comment: Ah--could you point me to a resource where I might read further?

Comment: But now I am questioning if my understanding of threads and processes is to be trusted at all. So am I right in picking processes over threads to perform two _huge_ matrix multiplications (computationally intensive) in parallel?

Comment: @scribe The python specific thing is that python's memory management is not thread safe, so only one thread per process is allowed to run at a time. As for matrix multiplication, the fastest option would actually be to use `numpy`, which is largely written in c and fortran, and therefore *can* (and does) run more than one thread at a time (and is compiled to machine code which is faster than interpreted code)

Comment: I indeed am using Numpy. But--I need to carry out two matrix multiplications which are independent of each other. I could perform one and then the other but that takes twice as long as it would if both could be performed simultaneously. I thought could run two processes each performing one multiplication at the same time.

Comment: @scribe with numpy either threads or processes should give you a speedup.  Presumably you'll want all of the results in one place at some point, which means that with the multiple-process route you'll need to transfer the results from one process to another.  With the multiple-threads approach, all of your results will already be in the same memory-space, which is probably an efficiency win for you since it avoids the transfer-the-results-over step.

Comment: But as I understand, threads are not really running in-parallel, they are just being juggled really fast. Which is why for i/o bound tasks they are the option but for computation bound tasks processes are since they actually do run on multiple cores.

Comment: That would be true if you were doing the matrix multiplies using Python code, but as @Aaron noted above Numpy's calculations are implemented in C, so the GIL restriction of the Python interpreter doesn't affect them.

Comment: Numpy is likely already using threads for heavy linear algebra unless you specifically disabled it (depends on the function I guess...), so adding your own threads or processes may not give any real speedup (check total cpu usage to see if all cores are used by python process). That said, it's always important to profile your code. Guessing where the slowdown is, and what will speed it up is just an exercise in frustration. Confirm first that the slowdown is where you think, then systematically test any time you make modifications. Sometimes slowdowns come from unexpected places.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: To be clear, the GIL restriction *can* affect them. It's not about being implemented in C, it's about whether the C code manually releases the GIL or not before doing the purely C level work. Some C extensions don't bother, some (e.g. Python's built-in `hashlib`) dynamically choose whether to release the GIL based on the amount of work they're about to do, etc. C level is not a guarantee of GIL release, by itself. I believe `numpy` does seem to release unconditionally, but it's hard to trace the code, and I may have missed something (it's a bad design if they do).